# Printing numbers in a 4 by 4 grid in the most efficient way

Tags: python

So I have this code that makes an array with 4 arrays in it each holding 4 values and it prints it in 4 rows and 4 columns. I was looking at the code and thought there was a more concise way of doing it so if anyone can think of any please tell me

```
import random
n=[[random.randint(0,100) for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
for i in range(len(n)):
    o=""
    for j in range(len(n[i])):
        o+=str(n[i][j])+" "
    print(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.join()` function is much more efficient than adding multiple strings. You can do it like:

```
import random
n=[[random.randint(0,100) for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
## n = [[64, 77, 76, 72], [43, 41, 30, 50], [59, 0, 34, 20], [41, 73, 81, 42]]


print(  "\n".join(  " ".join(str(value) for value in row) for row in n )  )
# Output: 
# 64 77 76 72
# 43 41 30 50
# 59 0 34 20
# 41 73 81 42
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
import random
n=[[str(random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]

for row in n:
    print('\t'.join(row))

OUTPUT:
53  34  62  45
21  45  39  94
52  75  53  94
88  16  97  80
```

I converted the numbers to string and applied the join method, joining each number with a tab ('\t').